# How to set height and width when creating PNG from SVG using PHP Imagick?

Tags: php, svg, resize, png, imagick

I am trying to generate PNG files dynamically out of SVG.

So lets say I have a SVG file `http://domain.tld/lib/img/svg/12345.svg` but I would like to call `http://domain.tld/png/12345/5000/` whichs results in a 5000px wide PNG image of my SVG file.

I have two issues:

1. The resizing don't work as i mentioned because the PNG firstly gets the dimensions of the SVG and is beeing upscaled afterwards whichs results in some ugly looking PNG as you can imagine. But I wonder how to tell the script: "Create PNG from SVG in dimensions x/y" ??
2. In the moment I need to create a temporary PNG file which is printed out instead of a fully dynamically created one. (Otherwise I always get told the image contains errors. But if I save it and load it again it works. But it sucks...)

Here is my code:

```
    $file = 'lib/img/svg/12345.svg';
    $size = 5000;

    $temp = 'lib/img/png/temp/12345.png';

    $img = new Imagick();
    $img->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $svg = file_get_contents($file);
    $img->readImageBlob($svg);
    $img->setImageFormat('png24');
    $img->resizeImage($size, 0, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
    $img->writeImage($temp);
    $img->clear();

    $img = imagecreatefrompng($temp);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagealphablending($img,false);
    imagesavealpha($img,true);
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [adaptiveResizeImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.adaptiveresizeimage.php) function, if you want to resize a JPEG image:

```
// jpeg
$im->adaptiveResizeImage(512, 512); // width and height
```

Or use the [resizeImage](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.resizeimage.php) function with a filter, if you want to resize a PNG image:

```
// png
$im->resizeImage(512, 512, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1); // width and height
```